# Reference document for .s file used by arm compiler

Tags: armcc

I am trying to use a `.s` file for `armcc` compilation.
If anyone got any pointers to some document which will be helpful for the same.
Can you please forward the same.

Thanks
Roshan

Answer (score 0):

In general **armasm** is used for compiling .s files to object code files (.o). I assume armcc will only work with .c files, with an option to have a .s converted file.

this link provides information on arm assembler usage:
[ARM Compiler armasm User Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473j/deb1353594352617.html)